# how to insert items into an array that is being returned by a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this function that returns an Array, i'm trying to insert new content into the array, how can I do this? I tried this way, but is not working

```js
function getAllVideos() {
    return [
        {title: 'My First Vlog', category: 'vlog'},
        {title: 'Mortal Kombat X Review', category: 'games'}
    ]
}

getAllVideos().push({title: 'Some News', category: 'vlog'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does, in fact, add a new item to the returned array. You are just not capturing that array so the change isn't permanent. Every time you call the function, there is a new Array instance returned - it will never be the same array twice because it's being created as an array literal within the function when you call it.

```js
function getAllVideos() {
    return [
        {title: 'My First Vlog', category: 'vlog'},
        {title: 'Mortal Kombat X Review', category: 'games'}
    ]
}

// Capture the return value
let result = getAllVideos();

// Add to the array
result.push({title: 'Some News', category: 'vlog'});

console.log(result);  // Verify
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign it to a var.

```js
function getAllVideos() {
    return [
        {title: 'My First Vlog', category: 'vlog'},
        {title: 'Mortal Kombat X Review', category: 'games'}
    ]
}

var temp = getAllVideos()
temp.push({title: 'Some News', category: 'vlog'})
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from the ones already here?

Comment: When I wrote it there were no answers.

Comment: That's not true. There were two answers for about 15 minutes before you answered.

Comment: So either I am lying, or it took me 15 min to write my answer. I'll let you decide.

Comment: Hover your mouse over your answer time and then the other answers. I was wrong. It wasn't 15 minutes, but it was 5 minutes for one and 6 for the other. I'm just saying that your answer came significantly after others and doesn't add anything new that the other answers already posted. In those cases, you should just delete your answer. Also, your answer doesn't actually even state what the problem was, you just proposed a solution without even explaining how the solution helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getAllVideos() {
    return [
        {title: 'My First Vlog', category: 'vlog'},
        {title: 'Mortal Kombat X Review', category: 'games'}
    ]
}

let allVideos = getAllVideos()
allVideos.push({title: 'Some News', category: 'vlog'})
console.log(allVideos);
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Scott Marcus you've to save the value in a variable

```
var results = [];

function getAllVideos() {
    return [
        {title: 'My First Vlog', category: 'vlog'},
        {title: 'Mortal Kombat X Review', category: 'games'}
    ]
}

results = getAllVideos();
results.push({title: 'Some News', category: 'vlog'});
```

Output:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {title: "My First Vlog", category: "vlog"}
1: {title: "Mortal Kombat X Review", category: "games"}
2: {title: "Some News", category: "vlog"}
length: 3
```

Comment: So how does this answer differ from the ones already here?

Comment: In any way as everyone can see! The fact is that when I was answering I wasn't able to see part of your answer as I can now...(only the first part "Your code does, in fact, add a new item to the returned array. You are just not capturing that array so the change isn't permanent.") that's why I answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to track the value of the current videos

```js
function getAllVideos(...rest) {

    if(!this.value) {
    this.value = [
        {title: 'My First Vlog', category: 'vlog'},
        {title: 'Mortal Kombat X Review', category: 'games'}
    ]
   }
  rest.forEach(item => this.value.push(item))
  
  return this.value
}
console.log(getAllVideos())
console.log(getAllVideos({title: 'Some News', category: 'vlog'}))
console.log(getAllVideos({title: 'Some News', category: 'vlog'}))
```